# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when do Pipenv

Tags: pip, pipenv

I'm currently working on a Flask in Heroku and also Using pipenv previouly but now when I try to in install pandas with pipenv it seems to not working.

I tried `pipenv install pandas` But it says ✘ Locking Failed.

I do try `pipenv lock --clear` `pipenv update` But it seem to be broke when locking file too.

And this is my log from terminal.

````
Installing pandas…
Adding pandas to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (ff302a) out of date, updating to (66581f)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  .
  .
  .
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 213, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Users/mattjunk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/1s/y6f8nx1d56s9syqmg27n2x8m0000gn/T/tmpg2os70vfbuild/hashlib/
(friends-trip) (base) Maitrees-MacBook-Air:friends-trip mattjunk$ ```
````